# How to interpret a "% win probability"?

Tags: probability, confidence-interval

I came across this [explanation](https://www.usalaxmagazine.com/college/women/beyond-the-basics-understanding-the-uses-of-win-probability) about a 61% win probability:

> 61 percent should be interpreted as: “if these teams played 100 times,
> we would expect Marquette to win 61 of those games.” It definitely
> does not mean that the model is 61 percent confident that Marquette
> will win.

So my questions are:

- Why a "% win probability" isn't the same as "the confidence a model has in a specific outcome"?
- How would this "confidence of a specific model has in a specific outcome" be stated in a short formulation (by short formulation I mean something like how "% win probability" stands as a short for "if this event would be run 100 times, then we would this specific outcome X times")?

Comment: Until there is a definition for being 61% confident that Marquette will win, this is going to be hard to address, since colloquial English makes those sound about the same. Do you specifically mean something about a confidence interval?

Comment: This sounds like the writer is trying to distinguish between an estimate of the win probability and the precision of that estimate.  Unfortunately, they don't seem to provide any explanation of what they mean.

Comment: I want to see those MCMC runs where Marquette wins 610 out of 1000 simulations. :P *Trace plot or it didn't happen*.

Comment: The simplest answer, and the one that makes the most sense, is that the author has no idea what he is talking about. He probably took some statistics 101 class and the recalled something about $p$-values and how they do not measure how certain you are in a hypothesis but rather something else. Then he confused himself and just repeated that sentence again.

Comment: @whuber, that's also what I thought the author meant, but I wondered why he pinpointed the formulation "% win probability" to a particular meaning while from the comments here, it doesn't seem to have a clear definition. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Dave, I don't mean anything, I just try to understand what the author wrote, but apparently, he didn't rely on well-known statistical definition which I thought he had done (like the "probability of precipitation" in weather forecasting).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments, that on it's own, the plain language implication of the quote is that a 61 percent win probability would mean that the team is predicted to win a game with 61 percent probability.  However, I think the article is getting at the idea of a predictive model that takes into account other factors. For example, the article talks about how the prediction can change over the course of a game, as one team gains a lead in points over the other team.  Presumably a good model would take into account other factors, like if the team is the home team or the away team. The language in the article could be made a little more precise, or simply coin some terms to make the distinction more clear.